# Custom HTML Element or Module - Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first - rendered HTML issue

Tags: html, image, contao

In `Contao 3.5.4` I'm trying to to use the `html5` `<picture>` element in a `Custom HTML` module.

This is the code:

`<div class="logo col-xs-6">
    <picture>
        <source srcset="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <source srcset="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.png" type="image/png">
        <img src="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.png" alt="Well-Made">
    </picture>
</div>`

But when I look at the rendered HTML it shows as:

`<div class="logo col-xs-6">
    &lt;picture>
        <source srcset="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <source srcset="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.png" type="image/png">
        <img src="files/wellmade_2015/images/logo.png" alt="Well-Made">
    &lt;/picture>
</div>`

And I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am using the right DOCTYPE `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

- Contao URL: http://www.well-made.nl/home.html (Not working)
- HTML Recreation URL: http://www.well-made.nl/test.html (working picture tag)

Comment: Looks like it is a problem with all types of `custom HTML` elements in `Contao`. I am getting the following error in the HTML editor `start tag seen without seeing a doctype first.`. Any clue why? **Yes I do have a doctype ;)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Look at system-settings for allowed HTML-elements. Add the missing ones. e.g.< picture >,< a >...

Thanks to [Andreas](https://community.contao.org/en/showthread.php?23031-Custom-HTML-Element-or-Module-Start-tag-seen-without-seeing-a-doctype-first&p=98683&viewfull=1#post98683)